# Handling a JSON Response

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I have Asp.net Api to get JSON response like this:

```json
{\"UserID\":5,\"UserName\":\"asd\",\"Password\":\"asd\",\"Email\":\"ss@asd\",\"PhoneNumber\":\"1213\",\"Logtit\":0.0,\"Latitle\":0.0,\"OfGroup\":\"a \"}
```

How can I handle this JSON response in Android Studio Using Volley Lib?

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


RequestQueue  requestqueue;
Button start;
TextView textView;
EditText ee;
public String givenValue = ee.getText().toString();
public String URL = "http://localhost:61511:8010/api/Feedback/5" ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    requestqueue=Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
   final Button start =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnget);
   final TextView textView =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTextView);
   final EditText ee =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.idtxt) ;
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("User");
                        for(int i= 0 ;i < jsonArray.length();i++){
                            JSONObject User = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e ) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Log.e("Volley", "ERROR");
                        }
                    }
            );
            requestqueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);}
    });
}
```

Comment: is this all json you are getting?

Comment: yes this all Json i get

Comment: "{\"UserID\":5,\"UserName\":\"asd\",\"Password\":\"asd\",\"Email\":\"ss@asd\",\"PhoneNumber\":\"1213\",\"Logtit\":0.0,\"Latitle\":0.0,\"OfGroup\":\"a \"}"

Comment: @Ahmed What exactly you wanna do with this response JSONObject

Comment: If you want to convert into a Java Object you can use Gson for that

Comment: i want to Handle this to View in TextView and save into Sqlite

Comment: so don't use JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("User");
                       Directly get ..  String str=response.getString("UserID");... all like this

Comment: this is corecct??

Comment: public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject ob = response.getJSONObject("UserID");
                            String name = ob.getString("UserID");
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are getting a string respone. If its a string then firstly conver it to Json Object.. you can do this as following below.

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
```

If it is JSONObject already then try to conver it to java object as following:

```
int userId=jsonObject.getInt("UserID");
String userName=jsonObject.getString("UserName");
String pass=jsonObject.getString("Password");
```

Put the code in your onResponse. and lastly seems like you are getting an array of object. Then create a POJO class like below:

```
    public class UserData {
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("UserId")
    private int userId;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("UserName")
    private String userName;
    .
    .
    .
   //add the extra attribute and create getter and setter

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}
```

Then in declare in your code:

```
ArrayList<UserData>userDataList=new ArrayList();
```

Follow the below method to set data to arraylist with json data parsing

```
int userId=jsonObject.getInt("UserID");
String userName=jsonObject.getString("UserName");
String pass=jsonObject.getString("Password");    
UserData userInfo=new UserData();
userInfo.setUserId(userId)
userIfo.setUserName(userName);
//add the other attribute similiarly
userDataList.add(userInfo);
```

Comment: Tnx For Your Help i handel My code Can you see it in Answer

Answer (score 0):

You could parse it into a Map using GSON.
Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54035895/how-to-parse-json-using-volley/54036257#54036257) question and answer for more information.