# How to fix org.json.JSONException: on Volley?

Tags: java, android, json, httprequest, android-volley

I am developing Login on android via connection with php (web).

**Code**

```
package com.example.salmakhalil.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText email,password;
    private Button btn_login;
    private TextView link_regist;
    private ProgressBar loading;
    private static String URL_LOGIN="http://192.168.8.101/android_register_login/login.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        loading=findViewById(R.id.loading);
        email=findViewById(R.id.email);
        password=findViewById(R.id.password);
        btn_login=findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        link_regist=findViewById(R.id.link_regist);

        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String mEmail=email.getText().toString().trim();
                String mPass=password.getText().toString().trim();
                if (!mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPass.isEmpty()){
                    Login(mEmail,mPass);
                }
                else {
                    email.setError("Please insert email");
                    password.setError("Please insert Password");
                }
            }
        });

        link_regist.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }

    private void Login(String email, String password){
        loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btn_login.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

//I think here facing a problem

```
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_LOGIN,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                            String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                            JSONArray jsonArray=jsonObject.getJSONArray("login");


                            if (success.equals("1")) {
                               for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                   JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                   String name = object.getString("name").trim();
                                   String email=object.getString( "email").trim();
                                   Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                                           "Success Login. \nYour Name : "
                                                   +name+"\nYour Email : "
                                                   +email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                           .show();
                                   loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                               }

                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            loading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btn_login.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error!!! " +e.toString(),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Error!! " +error.toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("email", email);
                params.put("password", password);
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


    }
}
```

When I click on the login Button, its showing thee error

> org.json.JSONException: No value for success.

I'm all the day trying to fix it. I have read other posts on Stack, no one helped me. I hope you can help me. Thanks.

Comment: the response does not have a `success` key in it's JSON

Comment: check your service in postman to know if it has `success` key in `response`

Comment: http://192.168.8.101 this is local ip. Do you have a public ip ?

Comment: @JitenderDev yes, this is local IP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `jsonObject` your receive in `onResponse()` does not have a value for entry  **"success"**

You should use the method `jsonObject.optString("success");` instead of `jsonObject.getString("success");`

`optString("success")` returns the empty string ("") if the key **"success"** doesn't exist. `getString("success")` on the other hand throws a JSONException.

Comment: Thank you, the error is dis-appeared, but  app is not responding. Only Loading!

Comment: Its likely not doing anything as you've only changed to using optString instead of getString. Your underlying problem still exists in that your JSON object doesn't have a key called success, changing to optString as @matdev said returns an empty string if the key doesn't exist instead of throwing the JSON exception. Use Postman or Insomnia to send the request to the API and confirm the structure of your JSON objects response and check that the `success` key does indeed exist in the root of the JSON object

Comment: @Boardy thank you for response. How I use Postman to send the request to the API

Comment: I've not used Postman myself, I use insomnia (https://insomnia.rest/). Its far simpler to Postman and the docs for it are pretty good

Comment: Yes, you all are right that jsonObject does not getting the entry "success". Because, I did typo mistake on php side placed "sucess" instead of "success". So, just corrected it and everything is now fixed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Boardy one more thing, I just saw some tutorial and pasted the code of Json and volley library code. I don't know how actually its work and complete procedure. Could you please send me any good tutorials of this for learning.

Comment: Glad its working now. I've not used Volley myself so I don't know any tutorials for it I'm afraid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199570/discussion-between-salma-khalil-and-boardy).

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the response that is supposed to get. I think the response doesn't contain any field name "success". Query on postman to get response otherwise talk to your back end developer.

Comment: Yes, you all are right that jsonObject does not getting the entry "success". Because, I did typo mistake on php side placed "sucess" instead of "success". So, just corrected it and everything is now fixed. Thanks a lot! –

Comment: thank you so much. one more thing, I just saw some tutorial and pasted the code of Json and volley library code. I don't know how actually its work and complete procedure. Could you please send me any good tutorials of this for learning.

Comment: Okay. I will try

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54667199/handling-a-json-response/54668004#54668004 see my answer here. it may help you